# Cannot access all property in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openweathermap

I have a component with some call to the OpenWeatherMap API. I use useState and useEffect and I render a component displaying the data. I can access some property of the object I get in return of the API call but not all of them...

This is what I receive ([openweathermap doc](https://openweathermap.org/current)):

```
{"coord": { "lon": 139,"lat": 35},
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 281.52,
    "feels_like": 278.99,
    "temp_min": 280.15,
    "temp_max": 283.71,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "humidity": 93
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.47,
    "deg": 107.538
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 2
  },
  "dt": 1560350192,
  "sys": {
    "type": 3,
    "id": 2019346,
    "message": 0.0065,
    "country": "JP",
    "sunrise": 1560281377,
    "sunset": 1560333478
  },
  "timezone": 32400,
  "id": 1851632,
  "name": "Shuzenji",
  "cod": 200
}
```

I can access the id, the name, the timezone... But I cannot get the `weather[0].icon` I get an error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. I should be able to access either all properties or none. But only some of them, how come? Those data come from the same API call so I guess it has nothing to do with an "asyns" issue. Or could it ? I seem to struggle with this...

Comment: because weather is an array. Should be `weather[0].icon`

Comment: I changed and edited the question, but it still does not work... The error is now `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The `[` means that `weather` is an array.

Try using `weather[0].icon`.